# set a style value from a javascript var

Tags: javascript, html, css, styles, height

I want to set the height of a cell in a table but i want to be dynamically. I take the height of the window from javascript and then i want to embed it in div style.

```
<script language="javascript">
var width = isNaN(window.innerWidth) ? window.clientWidth : window.innerWidth;
var height = isNaN(window.innerHeight) ? window.clientHeight : window.innerHeight;

if (height>900 )
{
    set_height = "500px";
} else if (height>700 && height<900) {
    set_height = "400px";
} else if (height>500 && height<700) {
    set_height = "300px";
} else if (height>300 && height<500) {
    set_height = "300px";
}
</script>
<table border ="1">
<tr><td>
<div style="height: set_height">
</div>
</td></tr>
</table>
```

IS IT POSSIBLE?

Comment: Add an ID to your `div`, wrap your code in window load function, and use `document.getElementById('yourdiv').style.height = set_height`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As mentioned, add an ID to your `div`:

```
<table border="1">
    <tr>
        <td>
            <div id="mydiv"></div>
        </td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Wrap your JS in a `window.onload` function and add the height by identifying your div:

```
window.onload = function () {
    var width = isNaN(window.innerWidth) ? window.clientWidth : window.innerWidth;
    var height = isNaN(window.innerHeight) ? window.clientHeight : window.innerHeight;

    if (height > 900) {
        set_height = "500px";
    } else if (height > 700 && height < 900) {
        set_height = "400px";
    } else if (height > 500 && height < 700) {
        set_height = "300px";
    } else if (height > 300 && height < 500) {
        set_height = "300px";
    }

    // Identify your  div by the ID you just put on it and add the height.
    document.getElementById('mydiv').style.height = set_height;
}
```

If you want this function to be called when your window resizes you just replace `window.onload` with `window.onresize`:

```
window.onresize = function() {
    // code as above
}
```

And trigger it so it works on window load:

```
window.onresize();
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/2wgJf/)

Answer (score 0):

If by "dynamic" you mean you want it to change then what you would need to do is change the style value every time a specific event is fired, say for example when the window resizes.

Something like this:

```
window.onresize = function () {
    var width = isNaN(window.innerWidth) ? window.clientWidth : window.innerWidth;
    var height = isNaN(window.innerHeight) ? window.clientHeight : window.innerHeight;

    if (height > 900) {
        set_height = "500px";
    } else if (height > 700 && height < 900) {
        set_height = "400px";
    } else if (height > 500 && height < 700) {
        set_height = "300px";
    } else if (height > 300 && height < 500) {
        set_height = "300px";
    }

    document.getElementById('myDiv').style.height = set_height;
};
window.onresize();
```

assuming your DIV has an `id` value of `myDiv`, for example:

```
<div id="myDiv">
</div>
```

[Here is a working example](http://jsfiddle.net/jXMXV/)

NOTE: I may have misunderstood the question, if you just want it to load when the page loads (one time only) then you can use the `window.onload` event instead

Answer (score 0):

best way for this goal is:

```
<script>
var set_height = "10px"
document.getElementById('test').style.height = set_height;
</script>

<div id='test'></div>
```